# fscanf - strcmp - from file - print name for corresponding id

Tags: c

**WARNING:** code is completely non functional. probably has many mistakes.

**intent:** print name for the id from database: **file.txt**

file.txt  ( id, name )

```
1 ooo
2 eee
3 zzz
```

test.c : ( just a sketch. **does not work** ).

Although the script below does not work. my intent is to make it work as is. and not use some other method. because I have a feeling this would be a very logical method with very little lines of code. in the example below I TRIED to get the name for **id 3**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

main()
{

    FILE *fff;
    fff = fopen("/file.txt","r");
    char *name;

    int r, line = 0, found = 0;
    float id;

    r = fscanf(fff, "%f %s\n", &id, name);

    while (r != EOF){
        line++;

        if(strcmp("3", id) == 0){
            printf("%s",name);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Very often, using `scanf()` and then saying "reading lines" are best handled by saying "use `fgets()` and `sscanf()`", and not using `scanf()` directly.

Comment: Note that the old C standard (C99; as opposed to the archaic C90 standard, or the current C11 standard) requires you to specify a return type for every function, including `main()`.

Comment: check the return value of `fpoen` before using it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has multiple problems:

- You should use a local array to read the string instead of an uninitialized pointer.
- You should use the type `int` for `id` as they seem to be whole numbers with a reasonably small range.
- You should check if `fopen()` succeeded at opening the file.
- You should pass the maximum number of chars to store into the `name` array to avoid a potential buffer overflow.
- The proper check for `fscanf()` success is comparing its return value to the number of expected conversions.
- You should compare numbers with the `==` operator, `strcmp` is for C strings.
- You should close the file.
- You should define `main()` as returning an `int` and return `0` upon successful operation.
- Keeping track of line numbers with `fscanf()` is impossible: this function treats newlines and white space indifferently and ignores it before numbers and strings.
- If you want to stop when a match is found, use the `break` statement.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char name[100];    
    FILE *fff;
    int found = 0;
    int id;

    fff = fopen("/file.txt", "r");
    if (fff == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open input file /file.txt: %s\n",
                strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }
    while (fscanf(fff, "%d %99s", &id, name) == 2) {
        if (id == 3) {
            printf("%s\n", name);
            found = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    /* you could do something with the found indicator */
    //if (found == 0) printf("no match for id == 3\n");

    fclose(fff);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would like the "searching" to "stop" once a match is found. I hope the answer I choose above does that. such fear came to my mind after I noticed the **%d matches** in your code.

Comment: it is probably true : **if (id == 3)** is much better than **strcmp**. this portion I will copy for sure.

Comment: @UnreasonableDirection: I updated the answer for your goal.  What to do upon match is a specification issue, multiple possibilities but no fear -;)  The answer above does that, but it has a few shortcomings, such as running an infinite loop on unexpected input: try this simple contents for `/file.txt`: `1`

Comment: I listed many problems, read and try to understand each one and how it is addressed in the code posted. It is OK to copy code as long as you understand what it does and keep the whole program consistent, otherwise it will most likely fail, especially in C.

Comment: i switched the answer to this because this one has 2 specialties. ability to not even bother using strcmp and also ability to break (stop seeking) after the first match. ( I am not certain if the previously chosen answer had the ability to stop after the first match )

Comment: @UnreasonableDirection: you cannot keep track of lines with `fscanf()`.  When given `%d %99s` as a conversion specification, `fscanf()` will attempt to read a integer followed by a word. If it succeeds, it will return 2, if only an integer is present, it will return 1, if a non integer is present first, it will return 0, and it will return `EOF` only if nothing can be read from the stream because it is at end of file or an error occurred.

Comment: If you want to keep track of line numbers, you must read lines with `fgets()` and parse them with `sscanf()`.  It is a much safer approach and allows better error detection and handling.